# How to display sql query for forgot password

Tags: php, mysql, forgot-password

I'm new to php/mysql and I'm wondering how i would accomplish a *"forgot my password"* page that displays the question the user filled out during the registration.

I've got a query but I can't seem to get it to work

```
$emailcheck = $_POST['email'];
$checkit = mysql_query("SELECT * Security_Question FROM users WHERE email ='$emailcheck'")
```

so my question is how would i display "Security Question"?

Comment: remove the * from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the mysql_fetch_array() method to extract the data from your query resource:

```
$emailcheck = $_POST['email'];
$checkit = mysql_query("SELECT Security_Question FROM users WHERE email ='$emailcheck'"); //fixed query syntax*
if (!$checkit) exit(); //don't forget to catch query errors!
$result = mysql_fetch_array($checkit);
$question = $result['Security_Question'];
```

`$question` will hold the security question.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is incorrect.

```
$checkit = mysql_query("SELECT Security_Question FROM users WHERE email ='$emailcheck'");
```

or

```
$checkit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='$emailcheck'");
```

You shouldn't be using a POSTed variable directly in your SQL either.  Atleast santize it first, or mysql escape it.  Better yet try using prepared statements,

```
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
```